# How to set up MX records and CNAME to Google Apps

Tags: hosting, dns, google-apps

I need to set up the basic configurations of MX Records and CNAME so my domain can be used with Google Apps, such as Gmail and Google Docs.

The problem is that my domain is hosted on GoDaddy and my actually site is hosted on another company, iWeb.

Where should I make the MX Records and CNAME configurations? On my GoDaddy's domain DNS manager or the WHM panel of my dedicated server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an [Edit DNS Zone](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/EditZone) item on WHM and you should be able to add MX and CNAME records for your domain. Then wait for the new settings to be propagated across the Internet.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually what I was thinking. 

The fact is that I don't know if that configuration of MX Records and CNAME must be done at the domain management or the hosting WHM panel.

Answer (score 0):

Either. You can point the domain name to your web host and from there point an mx record to Google. Or you can have the domain pointed to domain registrar's name servers and add an "A Record" to point to the web host's ip address and a MX Record to point to Google.